# How does this passive resistor network separate HS and LP signals from MIPI inputs?

Tags: fpga, passive-networks, max10

I'm currently trying to interface a MIPI camera with my FPGA, a 10M50 on an evaluation board.

The following schematic is taken from the documentation of the board and show how MIPI differential signal is receive by the board and split into 1 High Speed (HS) LVDS and 2 Low power (LP) CMOS signals.

[image: schematic of MIPI Rx port on MAX10 10M50 Evaluation Kit]

I'm trying to understand how this montage can separate the two signals and apply level-shifting.

I have found a similar montage in this documentation: [AN 754: MIPI D-PHY solution with passive resistor network](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/an/an754.pdf)

From what I understand of MIPI communication, the differential pair switch from LP for control (around 1.2V) and HS to transmit data (around 200mV). The I/O ports of the FPGA are unable to read the HS signal as is, so it need to be shifted to a voltage domain corresponding to the FPGA.

Input range from around 200mV (in HS mode) to 1.2V (in LP mode). On output side, HS is around 1.2V and LP are at 2.5V. see the MIPI receiver part in: [MAX10 Evaluation Kit User Guide](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/products/devkits/altera/documents/10M50_evaluation_board_userguide.pdf)

Can anyone enlighten me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the snippet is simple enough and is what it is but you haven't constrained your enquiry as to what voltage levels you are expecting from both outputs. And who knows what are outputs and inputs?

Comment: Why doubt it ? Read the spec

Comment: I don't doubt it, I need help understanding how it works

Comment: I could model it for you in Falstad’s web sim. But I have the basics see the eye diagram. (NPI)

Comment: I'll take a little time to try to understand your answer, I'll keep you updated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

HS up to 1.5Gbps and LP upto 10Mbps

HS 340mV into 50Ohms per side using CML current source to get +-340mV

LP uses 1.4V driver unipolar reduced to 0, 340mV by impedance divider as a CM signal while not causing HS imbalance of more than =≈5% differential offset.

So LP is a common mode voltage driver at <10M speed and HS is CML differential up to 1.5G all matched impedances.

2 wire analog phones work ≈this way using differential  current one way and differential voltage the other thru PHY hybrid XFMR.

Any questions?